# Orchard Recipe Add Page - Image Base Url

Tags: orchardcms

I am trying to add a page (homepage) in an orchard recipe that contains an image in HTML. However, the full URL of the image is dependent upon the deployment.

How can I use the base URL of the site in the recipe?

So far I've got this:

```
  <Data>
    <Page Id="/alias=" Status="Published">
      <BodyPart Text="&lt;p&gt;&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; src=&quot;~/Media/Default/Page/Homepage.png&quot; width=&quot;100%&quot; /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;" />
      <CommonPart Owner="/User.UserName=admin" />
      <AutoroutePart Alias="/" CustomPattern="/" UseCustomPattern="true" />
      <TitlePart Title="Home" />
    </Page>
  </Data>
```

But the normal `~` doesn't resolve to the base url.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Recipes don't support tokens or dynamic values, but that would definitely be a nice feature.

For now you will either have to implement such functionality yourself, or you could leave the url as is (starting with the tilde), and implement an IHtmlFilter that will actually process relative values at runtime.

Comment: Alternatively, if your site is not under a virtual directory, you can just remove the tilde. The browser will see it's a relative path, and append it for you to the domain name when requesting the image.